# Hangs when deleting large number of table view rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

The following code will hang.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (_empty) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 25000;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSMutableArray *collector = [@[] mutableCopy];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 25000; i++) {
        [collector addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }

    _empty = YES;

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[collector copy]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

I have filed a radar with apple for this (22865658).

Example project can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/upn9ee5svp11a1t/asdf.zip?dl=0

Comment: have you tried wrapping them in beginUpdates/endUpdates call if you are doing multiple changes?

Comment: yes. no difference. :(

Comment: There is no issue with enum or anything (Delete scenario). It is because that amount of huge data. Change that 25000 to something smaller (I used 250) and check.

Comment: your right about large data. but that's my question. why does it hang [in this situation] ?

Comment: @robdashnash: Seems like they can't handle that much data ;) Not sure what is happening, the UI is hanging because of `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` method. I put some logs and it shows that everything is working till that method call.

Comment: Are you asking for a practical reason? Do you actually have to solve that problem for your app? If not, I would leave it with Apple (you have filed a radar)